# How to use AND operator in mysql with Express framework

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I want to implement a query using AND operator in express framework using mysql.

**mysql query:** select * from questions where question_id=1 AND answer="apple" AND appkey="1122";

I want to implement the above query in express js using mysql. I have tried the below query.

```
req.getConnection(function(err,connection){


    var data = {

        qid    : input.questionid,
        ansvalue : input.answervalue,
        appid   : input.appkey,


    };
    console.log(data);

    var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM request_auth WHERE question_id = ?',[qid]'AND answer_description = ?',[ansvalue]'AND app_key = ?',[appid],function(err,rows)
    {

        if(query=='')
            console.log("Error Selecting : %s ",err );

        res.render('edit_customer',{page_title:"Edit Customers - Node.js",data:rows});


     });
```

but it is throwing error qid is not defined. Please give me solution for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to separate the actual query (with placeholders) and the placeholder parameters (see third example [here](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values)):

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM request_auth WHERE question_id = ? AND answer_description = ? AND app_key = ?', [qid, ansvalue, appid], ...)
```

Also, be sure that you're calling `connection.release()` when the query is done (more info [here](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections)).

Comment: Depending on the field type, would answer_description and app_key not need to be wrapped in '' or does that happen automatically? answer_description = '?'

Comment: @ChrisBint yeah, that will happen automatically :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm just throwing out a potential quick fix since I haven't worked with this framework before but you may need to add spaces before where your variables are being used because it seems it may not be using AND as it is seeing it as one long word.